# Generic Map with Lists of Comparable

Tags: java, generics, collections

I want a `Map` with several lists, each of them composed of `Comparable` objects, but not always the same, so there might be a `List` of `Doubles` and a `List` of `Strings`, etc...

`Map<String, List<Comparable<?>>>`

Unfortunately the `Map` as defined above will not be useful because the elements in each `List` can't be compared. Therefore I had to cheat and introduce a type parameter to the class:

```
class MyClass<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    Map<String, List<T>> myMap;
}
```

This is not totally correct because not all lists are of the same type. But it works, the only thing I have to do is to do a type cast to `T` when I add a `Double` to a list of doubles or a `String` to a list of strings. I make sure that each type gets added only to lists of the correct type.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

The alternative is to have one `Map` for every type of `List`. But this just would make the code uglier and the only thing I do with the lists is to sort them and insert them into a DB as String values, therefore I only call `toString` on the comparables.

Comment: You can use a [`checkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList-java.util.List-java.lang.Class-) to reduce the risk of error.

Comment: Since you cannot statically tell the Java compiler what the type of elements  in the `List` are, you can't even ensure that elements in one of the lists are comparable to each other. In short, you should either not do this, or accept that you're bypassing static type-checking, e.g. by declaring it as `Map<String, List<Comparable>>`, using the raw generic type `Comparable`. Then accept the compiler warnings telling you that you're bypassing static type-checking.

Comment: @shmosel wow, how comes I never heard about this? Thanks :)

Comment: @Andreas followed your suggestion, works great, only one warning. Why not write your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List<Object>` to make it generic and this purpose. 
You might want to do `instance of` checks for some specific datatypes inside list.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();

List<Object> list;

list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[] { 1, 2, 3.45, "dev", 'A', true, false }));
map.put("key1", list);

list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[] { false, 100, 5.1234f, "user", 'Z', true }));
map.put("key2", list);

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " => " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Output:
`key1 => [1, 2, 3.45, dev, A, true, false]
key2 => [false, 100, 5.1234, user, Z, true]`

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs of java generic wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) it says:

> In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard, represents an **unknown type**.

And also:

> The wildcard is never used as a type argument for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or a supertype.

So if you have the following declaration:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can't add anything to `list`, because you just told compiler that "I don't know the type of objects which are going to be put in `list`"

So your code `List<Comparable<?>>` means that "I want a list to contains comparable objects, but I don't know its type", which is not OK for compiler, because the compiler do need to know the type info for its work.

To use list contains any `Comparable` objects, you can use [upper bounded wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) like:

```
Map<String, List<? extends Comparable>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you're fine to put any `comparable` list as value for this map:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<? extends Comparable>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> as = new ArrayList<>();
    as.add(1);
    as.add(5);
    as.add(3);

    map.put("as", as);

    List<String> bs = new ArrayList<>();
    bs.add("hello");
    bs.add("world");
    bs.add("generics");

    map.put("bs", bs);
}
```

Finally I guess you'll be interested in [inheritance and subtypes in generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html), hope this could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is looking a bit like a heterogeneous map. What are you actually going to do with your list of comparables other than compare them?

However, if you want the lists to be of different types, then the indirection should be around the `List`.

```
public final class SortableList<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    private final List<T> elements;
    public SortableList(List<T> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
    public List<T> elements() {
        return elements;
    }
}

...

Map<String,SortableList<?>> sortables;
...
Comparable<?> colaMax = Collections.max(sortables.get("shirley").elements());
```